# I would like to make a function which is using picture and phone number in MMS

Tags: android

I would like to display the picture and phone number contained in an MMS, in my application. What API call(s) would I use to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Query Content Provider for `"content://mms"` URI. And from the `Cursor` project `NUMBER` and `MIMETYPE` or `DATA`. If you want to do this whenever MMS is received create BroadcastReceiver that will listen to incoming MMS for `WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` intent action and MIME type "application/vnd.wap.mms-message". Don't forget permissions to receive MMS.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html